# TabContainer of Ajaxtoolkit in asp.net not moving in design mode

Tags: asp.net

In Design mode, I'm not able to move Tabcontainer freely. It is very sticky and even after setting style="position: absolute" same behavior.

TabContainer will always stick to left corner of page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may use enter or tab keys to make that work.